# How is Mobile Device Info Dimension Determined by Analytics API?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Our team would like to analyze metrics for users running our app on a specific Android device. However, we notice that our Analytics data shows a large number of devices as "(not set)" for the "Mobile Device Info" dimension — often more than 50% of total sessions for a given time period.

A quick search on both Google and Stack Overflow shows that other Analytics users have encountered this issue of excessive "(not set)" entries in the past. But I've been unable to find any information about how the Analytics API fills this "Mobile Device Info" dimension.

**How exactly is the value of the "Mobile Device Info" dimension determined for a particular Google Analytics session?** Is it related to the

```
  Build.MANUFACTURER
```

and

```
 Build.MODEL constants in the Android API?
```

Our app is built with *Google Play Services v.8.1.0* and runs on Android 4.1 and later.

Comment: I recommend testing Secondary Dimensions such as Mobile Device Branding, Operating System and Screen Resolution to get more information about these people.

Comment: @JBrazier The Mobile Device Branding dimension for these entries also shows up as "(not set)".

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help any further than that; I've never observed this sort of behavior